# Change the font size and color in one specific row of listview (Android)

Tags: android, listview

Can anyone give examples of coding to change the font size and color in specific one row of listview like that was in the picture ... for example now clock 12:05 then 12:15 listview row (nearest time) will change color to red and big. thanks.[image]

Comment: please post some code what you try..

Comment: I think you'll need to extend ListView so that it applies changes you want to child closest to centre in onLayout()